# Selecting all entries between 4 grid locations

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite, google-maps

So I have a table and this table has two attibutes latitude and longitude both of type double. Now I have some idea about how to do a SELECT statement to get all the required rows but don't know how to put this togather or if it will be correct.

Basically I have an android map like so:
[image]
Each dot represents one edge of phones screen. Now the coordiantes come in form of Location object containing two attributes Latitude and Longitude.

How would I select all entries that have Longitude and Latitude inside this grid. My first try was

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (topLeftLatitude < latitude < topRightLatitude) AND (topLeftLongitude < longitude < topRightLongitude)
```

But I'm thinking this will only select the ones that are in horizontal line or ? After 10h resolving the DB issue I'm pretty confused here.

Comment: `Now I have some idea (...) but don't know (...) if it will be correct.` How about writing tests to see if it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select something within a square in general you need **four AND statements**, not sure if this is true for the Google maps API but I would guess something like this:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE (latitude > topLeftLatitude) AND (latitude < topRightLatitude) AND (topLeftLongitude > longitude) AND (bottomLeftLongitude < longitude)

Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Correcting: think about 180th meridian. ;)

Comment: Yea I had to draw it down on paper before I realized how stupid the question I asked really is xD It's the sleep deprevation : )